# Get WindowsIdentifiy from Operating system using a SID

Tags: c#, windows, windows-identity

I am sending request via WCF from Machine A to Machine B.
The domain and users are same on both machines.
In Machine B, using a given parameters, I want to create a `WindowsIdentity` for that user that invoked the operation from Machine A.

I know there is technology to do this via WCF infrastructure - but this technology is not enabled in my project.
So i need to send `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.User.Value` from Machine A to Machine B.

My question is how do I create a `WindowsIdentity` using a SID ? Or do i need to send different parameters ?

## Notes:

I was trying this:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "My_Domain");
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "userSID");
```

ofcourse with the right parameters, and then iterated all the GRP.GetMembers(true) to seek for mine - but it was not there.

## Update:

The User is: `DOMAIN_NT/MyUser123`  -> If i change it to `MyUser123@DOMAIN_NT` and create instance of `WindowsIdentity` `identity = new WindowsIdentitiy("MyUser123@DOMAIN_NT");` - It will work, but its an ugly way.